# How to use NFC to transfer image

Tags: android, nfc

I have created a simple app where I have an image. Now what I want to do is.

1. At first, I want to add NFC support to my app.
2. Once I add NFC support in my app, the next thing I want is how can I transfer my image that is present in my app to another device having NFC support.

If anyone knows please help me to solve this out, if possible with an example. I have gone through the documentation as provided in [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/docs) for NFC, but in that case, it only gives transfer of text from one device to another using NFC, but in my case I want to transfer image instead of text.

Code for text transfer

```
public class NFCTestApp extends Activity 
{   
                                
   private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
   private TextView mText;
   private NdefMessage mMessage;

    public static NdefRecord newTextRecord(byte[] text, Locale locale, boolean enco   deInUtf8) 
    {
       byte[] langBytes = locale.getLanguage().getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));

       Charset utfEncoding = encodeInUtf8 ? Charset.forName("UTF-8") : Charset.forName("UTF-16");
       byte[] textBytes = text;

       int utfBit = encodeInUtf8 ? 0 : (1 << 7);
       char status = (char) (utfBit + langBytes.length);

       byte[] data = new byte[1 + langBytes.length + textBytes.length]; 
       data[0] = (byte) status;
       System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, data, 1, langBytes.length);
       System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, data, 1 + langBytes.length, textBytes.length);

       return new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], data);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       
       Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
       ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       bm.compress(Bitmap.Compress.JPEG, 100, baos);
       byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

      // Create an NDEF message 
       mMessage = new NdefMessage(
            new NdefRecord[] { newTextRecord(b, Locale.ENGLISH, true)});  
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() 
    {
       super.onResume();
       if (mAdapter != null) mAdapter.enableForegroundNdefPush(this, mMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() 
    {
       super.onPause();
       if (mAdapter != null) mAdapter.disableForegroundNdefPush(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to include this in your manifest file to enable NFC support:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
```

Then you might have a look at [NFCDemo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NFCDemo/index.html), official NFC demo app from Google, for a reference.

Comment: Yeh i have gone through that documentation.I also work out with the example for transferring text.Now i want to transfer image instead of transferring Text.So is there any example of transferring image using peer to peer data exchange

Comment: I don't think so. But if you are able to send/receive text, it should be not a problem to send the image in chunks, since the actual transfer code I believe will not much deviate.

Comment: Actually for sending text i simply create a NDEF message with some sample text like mMessage = new NdefMessage(
                new NdefRecord[] { newTextRecord("NDEF Push Sample", Locale.ENGLISH, true)}); now for image what i should pass to NdefRecord

Comment: I have send you the code for transferring text..just check my edited answer..Now please tell me where i should make changes for Tranferring images in my code

Comment: Just change newTextRecord() to accept byte[] instead of String, make appropriate changes, split your image to chunks, and send it one by another. You're almost there.

Comment: If you dont mine can you please me once how to do it..Actually i have no idea behind on it..i will be very thankful to you

Comment: Sorry, I am not going to write the whole solution for you. You've asked the question - I've answered.

Comment: Chunk = piece. Send the image piece by piece, not whole at one time. This is what I meant.

Comment: Thats what i want.how to do that..can you help me with some documentation

Comment: If you google, there is a bunch of examples. For example, this one: http://shirinjoshi.blogspot.com/2008/03/upload-file-using-chunks-of-bytes.html

Comment: Hey Andrejs..i have split the image and i edited my code..can u help me to solve these what are the changes i have to made in my newTextRecord() function...